# IOS 6 - NetConnection Close Issue

Tags: ios, air, freeze, wowza, netconnection

http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1070996

same error occurred in iPhone4(ios 6.1.3) and AIR SDK 3.7.

I attempt to close netconnection to the wowza server the app freezes and
can't control anything( only back push device home button).

adobe forum says it's seem to fix AIR 3.5 but not fixed in AIR SDK 3.7.

Does anyone know this problem?

Comment: I see the same problem with iPhone 4s, AIR SDK 3.8 and AMS dev. ed. 5.0.3: calling NetConnection.close() freezes the app for few minutes. On Android and BlackBerry this doesn't happen.